# Trying to change magento custom product list sorting like sort by special_price and most popular

Tags: magento

I tried:

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('topsellings', 'desc') ?>"<?php if ($this->isOrderCurrent('topsellings') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    Most Popular
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('special_price', 'desc') ?>"<?php if ($this->isOrderCurrent('special_price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    On Sale
</option>
```

but unable to get it. See [here](http://deluxemode.com/index.php/dresses/wedding-dress.html?dir=desc&order=topsellings) for the site. What am I missing?

Comment: does your code actually do anything? or is it giving you different results from what you want?

Comment: http://deluxemode.com/index.php/dresses/wedding-dress.html?dir=desc&order=topsellings   when i click on other most popular and on sale then its showing just old option highest and lowest price

Comment: only two option working , so i am amazing what  a issue

Answer (score 0):

To add a “custom” attribute, you must add the attribute into the array in the toolbar.php file. You can redeclare it(/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php ).

```
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_availableOrder = array(
        'position'  => $this->__('Best Value'),
        'entity_id' => $this->__('Newest'),
        'name'      => $this->__('Name'),
        'price'     => $this->__('Price'),
        'format'    => $this->__('Format'),
        //Custom attribute you have added.
        'release_date'    => $this->__('Release Date')
        );
```

then you can call the attribute from the array this by adding into the original thread posters code.

```
 <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('release_date', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('release_date') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Release Date
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the attribute value of field `used_for_sort_by` then the template should pick this change up and you will not need to change the template code. This can be done either via a setup script or can easily be set via the attribute management part admin section.

The function `getAttributesUsedForSortBy` in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config` will look for all attributes that have this flag set to true. The default template will update automatically becuase of the following.

```
<?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```